# Network stream receiving data mixed with '\0'

Tags: c#, encoding, tcp, networkstream

My server is sending the following data:

```
{
  "command": 23
}
```

My client is receiving the following data:

```
"{\0\r\0\n\0 \0 \0\"\0c\0o\0m\0m\0a\0n\0d\0\"\0:\0 \02\03\0\r\0\n\0}\0"
```

As you can see I'm receving the data sent, but with those `\0` mixed with it. `What is causing this?` Maybe something with the encoding?

Method from server which sends the data:

```
public void GetBasicInfo()
        {
            JObject o = new JObject();

            o.Add(COMMAND, (int)Command.GetBasicInfo);

            byte[] package = GetBytes(o.ToString());
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(o.ToString());
            networkStream.Write(package, 0, package.Length);
            networkStream.Flush();
        }

private static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            return bytes;
        }
```

Method from client which reads the data:

```
private void CommsHandler(TcpClient tcpClient)
        {
            NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    string message = ReadResponse(networkStream);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message);
                    ParseMessage(message);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    break;
                }

            }

            Logger.Log(LogType.Warning, "Communication with server closed");

            tcpClient.Close();
            SearchForServer();
        }

private static string ReadResponse(NetworkStream networkStream)
        {
            // Check to see if this NetworkStream is readable.
            if (networkStream.CanRead)
            {
                var myReadBuffer = new byte[256]; // Buffer to store the response bytes.
                var completeMessage = new StringBuilder();

                // Incoming message may be larger than the buffer size.
                do
                {
                    var numberOfBytesRead = networkStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
                    completeMessage.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead));
                } while (networkStream.DataAvailable);

                return completeMessage.ToString();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Everyone who has ever used a hex editor to peek inside a unicode text file or a unicode DLL/EXE knows this pattern of interleaved zeros... :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> As you can see I'm receving the data sent, but with those \0 mixed with it. What is causing this? Maybe something with the encoding?

Yes. It's this method:

```
private static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}
```

It's copying the `char` data in binary form - two bytes per character. Don't use this at all - just use `Encoding.GetBytes`, having chosen a suitable encoding... I'd suggest `Encoding.UTF8`. Use the same encoding on the receiving side. Note that you can't just use `Encoding.GetString` as you may receive data which ends half way through a character (if you have any non-ASCII data).

I'd also recommend against using `DataAvailable` as an indication of whether a message has finished or not. If you're sending multiple messages on the same stream, you should either length-prefix each message (probably the simplest approach) or use some specific data to indicate the end of the stream.